# How to remove blue border around objects in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to draw group of objects in center of canvas. But when I use `addWithUpdate` method - all objects whithin group has blue border. But if try to use `add` method of group - blue border gone, but I don't know how move group to center in this case.

[http://jsfiddle.net/*DR*/hrykgzks/](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/hrykgzks/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here you go**

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hrykgzks/1/

**JS**

```
canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(document.getElementById("schemaCanvas"));
group  = new fabric.Group();

side_a = new fabric.Line([0, 0, 200, 0], {
    stroke: "black",
    strokeWidth: 10,
    hasBorders: false
});
group.addWithUpdate(side_a);

side_b = new fabric.Line([200, 0, 200, 200], {
    stroke: "black",
    strokeWidth: 10,
    hasBorders: false
});
group.addWithUpdate(side_b);
canvas.centerObject(group);
canvas.add(group);
```